# Connection not closed after transaction completion HikariCP

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, transactions, hikaricp

Spring Boot Version :1.5.6 and Hikari Pool 2.7.3 And Hibernate

> **java.lang.Exception**: Apparent connection leak detected    at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
> at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
> at
> org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:386)
> at
> org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:87)
> at
> org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:112)
> at
> org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:230)
> at
> org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:237)
> at
> org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:214)
> at
> org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:52)
> at
> org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1512)
> at
> org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:45)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:189)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
> at
> org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
> at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:447)
> at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
> at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
> at
> ariba.sellerdirect.fileprocessor.processor.SingleItemProcessor$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a84b87d5.diffAndStoreMasterItem()
> at
> ariba.sellerdirect.fileprocessor.processor.csv.MasterContentCSVProcessor.processDiffAndStoreItem(MasterContentCSVProcessor.java:66)
> at
> ariba.sellerdirect.fileprocessor.processor.csv.MasterContentCSVProcessor.processSingleItem(MasterContentCSVProcessor.java:43)
> at
> ariba.sellerdirect.fileprocessor.processor.csv.GeneralCSVProcessor.processFile(GeneralCSVProcessor.java:109)
> at
> ariba.sellerdirect.fileprocessor.processor.csv.GeneralCSVProcessor$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6777a9.invoke()
> at
> org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
> at
> ariba.sellerdirect.util.PerformanceMonitorInterceptor.invokeUnderTrace(PerformanceMonitorInterceptor.java:24)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AbstractTraceInterceptor.invoke(AbstractTraceInterceptor.java:129)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)

Comment: You have any Hikari config in application.properties ? Can you add that

Comment: spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name = SellerDirect-HikariPool 
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout = 60000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime = 2000000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size = 5
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-prepared-statements = true
spring.datasource.hikari.leak-detection-threshold = 40000